React Hook Form Controller in React Native: Unable to Enter Decimal Values in Text Input
I am building a React Native app using react-hook-form and zod for form handling and validation. One of my fields, sellingPrice, is supposed to accept decimal values (e.g., 123.45). However, I am facing two main issues:
When I type a decimal (e.g., a dot .), it gets immediately deleted, preventing me from entering any decimal numbers.
The field is required and validated as a number, so I need to ensure the input is a valid number when the form is submitted.
Here’s my current setup:
Input
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="sellingPrice"
  render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
    <Input
      label="Selling Price"
      placeholder="Enter Selling Price"
      value={value !== undefined && value !== null ? value.toString() : ''}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      onChangeText={text => {
        const sanitizedText = text.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); // Remove invalid characters
        if (/^\d*\.?\d*$/.test(sanitizedText)) {
          onChange(sanitizedText); // Allow typing decimals
        }
      }}
      keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'decimal-pad' : 'numeric'}
    />
  )}
/>


Zod type:
  sellingPrice: z
    .number({message: 'Selling Price is required'})
    .positive('Selling Price must be positive')
    .transform(value => parseFloat(value.toFixed(2))), // Optional rounding to 2 decimals

I've the following:
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="sellingPrice"
          render={({field: {onChange, onBlur, value}}) => (
            <Input
              label="Selling Price"
              placeholder="Enter Selling Price"
              value={value?.toString() || ''} // Convert number to string and handle undefined
              onBlur={onBlur}
              disabled={isSubmitting}
              onChangeText={text => {
                // Allow only numbers with up to two decimal places
                const sanitizedText = text.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); // Remove invalid characters
                if (/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/.test(sanitizedText)) {
                  // Check decimal limit
                  onChange(sanitizedText);
                }
              }}
              keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'decimal-pad' : 'numeric'} // Use 'decimal-pad' for iOS
            />
          )}
        />

Which works if it's only a string value, but the form won't submit with this solution

I tried to run your code (but without zod)
And it seems to work correctly. (Here is a screen)
I am not that familiar with zod, it doesn't seem to change the input, but it worked without it, so maybe the problem is there.
If not, then it may be somewhere in the code you didn't show.
Here is code I tested
import { Platform, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const TempScreen = () => {
  const { control } = useForm({
    mode: 'all',
  });

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 40 }}>
    <Text>Temp Screen</Text>
    <Controller
    control={control}
    name="sellingPrice"
    render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
        // label="Selling Price"
        placeholder="Enter Selling Price"
        value={value?.toString() || ''} // Convert number to string and handle undefined
        onBlur={onBlur}
        // disabled={isSubmitting}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          // Allow only numbers with up to two decimal places
          const sanitizedText = text.replaceAll(/[^\d.]/g, ''); // Remove invalid characters
          if (/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/.test(sanitizedText)) {
            // Check decimal limit
            onChange(sanitizedText);
          }
        }}
        keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'decimal-pad' : 'numeric'} // Use 'decimal-pad' for iOS
      />
    )}
  />
</View>
);
};

export { TempScreen };


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
